# On a bull rush, do you have to shift into the creature's former space?

Tags: dnd-4e

[Bull rush](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=323) says that the character shifts into the vacated space.

Is this shift optional?  (It became highly important when there was a [Wall of Fire](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=722) last night!)

Comment: Based on the multitude of questions you and your friends have posted, it seems like last night was a really interesting night!

Comment: @Iszi We usually generate a fair number, was better about writing them down this time. :)  I get a lot dumber when I'm DMing and make some bone headed calls too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify: all non-forced movement is optional. Only when the power text explicitly requires that you move the full distance (and I couldn't find any instances of the term "must") Thus, any movement that is not forced movement is optional.

---

As per [Move](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=505) in the glossary:

> If a power notes a distance that you or an ally moves willingly (for example, “you shift 2 squares”), the character allowed to move can decide to move all, some, or none of that distance. Similarly, if a power forcibly moves an enemy (for example, “you push the target 3 squares”), you can decide to move the enemy all, some, or none of that distance.

Inasmuch as bull rush is a push 1 for the enemy, and then you shift into their square, it seems to fall squarely under the move rules, and thus isn't required. There are no feats that contradict that assumption. Should I contact cust serv for you? (Replies tend to be spotty and inconsistent, but if your GM isn't happy with the move ruling...)

Comment: As an example of forced movement that must occur see [Lightning Lure](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2078)[DDI]. If you don't pull the target adjacent (or can't do so for whatever reasons) you've just wasted your standard action.

Comment: I think the best explanation is a bit further down in the Move definition - "If a power notes the destination for your or an ally’s move ... the character allowed to move decides either to move to that destination or not."  I think that covers this situation exactly.  Thanks